# What is the minimum value of $a+b+\frac{1}{ab}$ if $a^2 + b^2 = 1$?

Tags: inequality

For the case when $a,b>0,$ I used AM-GM Inequality as follows that:

$\frac{(a+b+\frac{1}{ab})}{3} \geq (ab\frac{1}{ab})^\frac{1}{3}$

This implies that $(a+b+\frac{1}{ab})\geq 3$. Hence, the minimum value of $(a+b+\frac{1}{ab})$ is 3

But the answer is $2+\sqrt{2}$ ... how is it ?

Comment: $\frac{1}{ab}$ isn't independent from $a$ and $b$, so you can't reach the equality case for the AM-GM inequality.

Comment: Solve $a^2+b^2=1$ for b (distinguish cases), and pluf this b in the first equation. Then study this as a function of a.

Comment: Equality is obtained in your AM-GM when all the terms are equal, i.e. $a=b=\frac1{ab}$.  But that is not consistent with the constraint, so you cannot reach the minimum suggested by that application of AM-GM.  Of course it still remains a lower bound, as you can note, $2+\sqrt2 > 3$.

Comment: solve for $a$ and you will have $a=(+-)\sqrt (1-b^2)$ then let $f(x)=(+-)\sqrt (1-x^2) +x(+-)\frac{1}{x\sqrt(1-x^2)}$. Find the min of this function using derivatives

Comment: Did you forget another constraint such as $a,b>0$?

Comment: @AnwesaDey Please observe that to apply AM-GM inequality, all quantities must be non-negative. As  Hagen von Eitzen noticed, you must have forgotten something.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use AM-GM for this, you need to ensure that the equality condition can be met along with the constraint, by "balancing coefficients".  Illustrated below:

$$a+b+\frac1{ab} = a+b +\frac{1}{2\sqrt2 ab}+\left(1-\frac1{2\sqrt2}\right)\frac1{ab}$$

Now by AM-GM, 
$$  a+b +\frac{1}{2\sqrt2 ab}\ge \frac{3}{\sqrt2}$$

and for the remaining term we have again
$$\left(1-\frac1{2\sqrt2}\right)\frac1{ab} \ge \left(1-\frac1{2\sqrt2}\right)\frac{2}{a^2+b^2} = 2-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$$

Combining these results, we have $a+b+\dfrac1{ab} \ge 2 + \sqrt2$, with equality iff $a=b=\frac1{\sqrt2}$.

---

Added: The key here is of course knowing how to split the LHS, which is by noting that if for equality we need $a=b=\dfrac1{k~ab}$ and for the constraint we need $a^2+b^2=1$, what could be the value of $k$.  The rest is then easy applications of AM-GM.

Comment: @ Macavity Could you please explain more on ensuring that the equality condition can be met along with the constraint ?
What is wrong if use the AM-GM inequality directly ,also how does the addition of the extra term allow for the equality constraint to be met ?

Comment: @SuryakantShrivastava If you use AM-GM directly, then equality is when $a=b=\frac1{ab}$ i.e. $a=b=1$.  But this would not satisfy the constraint $a^2+b^2=1$, so this won't work.  If equality is not possible, the bound that you get using equalities will never be a minimum / maximum, they remain merely bounds like $x^2 > -1$ or in the best case a supremum/ infimum like $1/x > 0$.  So to get a minimum, we need an inequality bound, and we need equality to be possible somewhere.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks , I understood why we need the equality bound . Now my next question is how did you think of using $2(2)^{\frac{-1}{2} $ .
Any intuition or general strategy ?

Comment: @SuryakantShrivastava Can't make out what you wrote, but the strategy is simple, make a guess and see if you can prove its right. In this case I guessed $a=b$ at minimum, which would mean theyre both $\frac1{\sqrt2}$, so for AM-GM equality I can combine only that part of the third term. The rest must seperately fend for itself.

Comment: @Macavity are there any resources on this "balancing of coefficients" method? I'm very intrigued.

Comment: @DatBoi Maybe https://www.isinj.com/mt-usamo/Secrets%20in%20Inequalities%20(volume%201)%20Pham%20Kim%20Hung.pdf Chapter 6 covers the essentials and will help.  Other books are there as well which contain the basic logic.

Comment: @Macavity the most essential pages 97&98 are miraculously missing!

Answer (score 3):

If $a,b>0$, one can make the substitution $u=ab,$ where $0<u\leq \frac 1 2$ (by AM-GM). Note that $$1=a^2+b^2=(a+b)^2-2ab,$$ hence $$a+b=\sqrt{1+2u}.$$ It follows that one needs to minimize $$f(u):=a+b+\frac 1{ab}=\sqrt{1+2u}+\frac 1 u, \qquad 0<u\leq \frac 1 2.$$

By Calculus, it is easy to see that $f$ has a global mimimum at $u_0\in (1,2)$ with $u_0^4-2u_0-1=0$, but $f$ is decreasing on $(0,\frac 1 2].$ It follows that $f$ achieves absolute minimum over $(0,\frac 1 2]$ at $u=\frac 1 2=ab,$ i.e. when $a=b=\frac{\sqrt{2}}2$ (the case of equality by AM-GM: $1=a^2+b^2\geq 2ab).$ Hence $$f(1/2)=2+\sqrt{2}$$ is the minimum of $a+b+\frac 1 {ab}.$ QED

Answer (score 2):

$2ab = (a+b)^2 - (a^2+b^2)$, hence we need to find the minimum value of $a + b + \frac{2}{(a+b)^2 - (a^2+b^2)}$ $ = a + b + \frac{2}{(a+b)^2 - 1}$.

Let us find the maximum value (k) of $a+b$ given $a^2+b^2=1$. Thinking graphically, when $a+b = k$ is tangent to the circle, its gradient is $-1$ and hence the gradient of the normal is $1$, or $a=b$. Hence $k = \frac{1}{\sqrt2} + \frac{1}{\sqrt2} = \sqrt{2}$, which gives $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{2} + \frac{2}{2-1} = 2 + \sqrt{2}$ as the answer.

This relies on the fact that $f(x) = x + \frac{2}{x^2 - 1}$ is decreasing for $x \in (1, \sqrt{2}]$. Partial fractions gives $f(x) = x + \frac{1}{x-1} - \frac{1}{x+1}$ and taking the derivative shows that $f'(x) < 0$ in the given interval. There might be a way without calculus.

Answer (score 1):

The minimum does not exist. Try $a>0$ and $b\rightarrow 0^-$.

Answer (score 1):

Let the minimum value of $a+b+\frac{1}{ab} = k$. Both curves must be tangent to each other, which means they must have the same gradient. Thus $a^2 + b^2  = 1 \implies \frac{db}{da} = -\frac{a}{b}$, and:

$$a+b+\frac{1}{ab} = k \implies 1 + \frac{db}{da} - \frac{1 + db/da}{(ab)^2} = 0$$

$$\implies (ab)^2 \left(1 - \frac{a}{b} \right) - 1 - -\frac{a}{b} = 0$$
$$\implies a^2b^2 - a^3b - 1 + \frac{a}{b}  =0$$
$$\implies a^2b^3 - a^3b^2 - b + a = 0$$
$$\implies a^2b^2(b-a) - (b-a)  =0$$
$$\implies (ab+1)(ab-1)(b-a) = 0$$

but only $b-a = 0$ intersects with $a^2 + b^2 = 1$. This gives $a = b = \frac{1}{\sqrt2}$, and hence $k = \frac{1}{\sqrt2} + \frac{1}{\sqrt2} + \frac{1}{1/2} = 2 + \sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Poor man's version of lagrange multipliers lol

Answer (score 0):

Constrant:
$$q=x^2 +y^2-1=0$$

Goal:
$$ c= x+ y + \frac{1}{xy}$$

Now, by LaGrange multipliers , we can say that:

$$ \nabla q =  \lambda \nabla c$$

Hence,

$$2x  = 1 - \frac{1}{x^2y} \tag{1}$$

$$ 2y = 1- \frac1{y^2 x} \tag{2}$$

By multiplication of $x$ in eqtn (1) and $y$ in eqtn (2):

$$ 2x^2 = x - \frac{1}{xy} \tag{3}$$

$$ 2y^2 = y - \frac{1}{yx} \tag{4}$$

Substract the two equations:

$$ 2(x^2 - y^2) = (x-y)$$

Now, either $x=y$ or $x+y = \frac12$, substitute this into the equation $(x+y)^2 -2xy -1 = 0$ while considering the constraints

$$ 2y^2 =1 \to (x, y)=\{(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2} }, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2} }) \}\tag5$$

$$ (\frac12)^2 -2xy -1 = 0 \to \frac{1}{xy}=-\frac83 \tag6$$

We can check that it is indeed eqtn (5) where the function extremizes with $2+ \sqrt{2}$